# Javascript Scope: variable declared inside as opposed to outside of a forEach loop

Tags: javascript

I am developing an application that uses the twitch API and in the process makes two AJAX requests, one inside another. A simplified version of my code:

```
twitchStreamers = ["name1","name2",...];
var language, views="", html = "";
//var status;
twitchStreamers.forEach(function(streamer) {
   // some code
   $.getJSON(streamURL, function(streamData) {
      var status;
      // some code
      if(condition){
         status = "some value 1";
      } else if(condition) {
         status = "some value 2";
      } else {
         status = "some value 3";
      }
      $.getJSON(channelURL, function(channelData) {
         // some code
         // access value of status
      }) // end of second ajax request
   }) // end of 1st ajax request
} //end of forEach loop
```

Notice the `status` variable.

This design works perfectly with what i want to do i.e. when i access the status variable inside the second ajax request, it has the correct value of `status` with respect to the current loop iteration. But when i declare the variable `status` outside forEach loop it always has the value `some value 3` (initialised in the else part of the conditionals) when accessed in the second AJAX request. Why is this so?

Note that the variable `status` is always initialised correctly in the first AJAX request irrespective of where the variable is declared.

Comment: Because when you declare it outside the loop, there is only one variable, which can only hold a single value, not three of them?

Comment: Do you understand [how closures work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work), and have you had a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example?rq=1)?

Comment: The problem you're having here is very similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example?noredirect=1&lq=1. The answers are instructive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic example of closures + loops. By placing the variable `status` outside of the forEach loop I was declaring it once. Subsequently when the loop ran and the second function started executing, it referred to the latest value that it was assigned i.e. `some value 3`. By placing it inside the loop, the variable will be declared not just once but at each iteration thereby storing the correct value `status` at each iteration.